# Validate that two keys of object should have same value using Joi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, validation, joi

I am using [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi) for object dalidation.
suppose my object is

```
// valid object
object1 = {
    "minimum_balance": 200,
    "initial_amount": 200,
    "name": "Alok"
}

// invalid object
object2 = {
    "minimum_balance": 250,
    "initial_amount": 200,
    "name": "Alok"
}
```

I want to add validation to this object that `minimum_balance` and `initial_amount` should be same using `joi`. I should get error if values of both key are not same.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
const minimum_balance = Joi.string().required().valid(Joi.ref('initial_amount')).options({
  language: {
    any: {
      allowOnly: '!!initial amount do not match',
    }
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
  fieldOne: Joi.string().required(),
  fieldTwo: Joi.string().allow(Joi.ref('fieldOne')).required()
});
```